# Corporate exchange server strips Solaris email attachement

Tags: email, solaris, binary

I need to send file(s) from a Solaris 11.3 server through the corporate network to a user on a PC .  I would like to eliminate winscp and automate this process.

This test works:
`` uuencode /var/adm/messages messages.txt | mailx -s "messages on `uname -n`" user@company.com ``

This test does not work:
`` uuencode ./abc.tar abc.tar | mailx -s "tar on `uname -n`" user@company.com ``
I get the email and an attachment.  Inside the attachment it says something like this:
`Per 2014-123-000 The attached file was removed because it has the potential to be harmful to the network.  Direct all questions to your point of contact.  blah blah blah`

I used tar as a test, but any binary including zip and compress get stripped at the user end.

Can the binary files be converted to another format to pass the filter, but still allow a novice user to extract user files at their end?

Comment: It is not the wisest of the ideas to use the email system to send files, specially largish files.The email filters just show they are doing their job properly.  I would advise setting up a service like a small web page. You could then send a link via email.

Comment: 1. Ask for a exception in your mail folder. Circumventing security measures is a security policy violation in some companies.
2. copy the file to a share used by both endpoints
3. Put it on a webserver  perhaps password protected

Comment: Rui F Ribeiro and @c0t0d0s0 have an interesting idea.

I can transfer these files (just logs really) to a machine that is hosting an Oracle Enterprise Manager 13c web based database monitoring tool.

This is somewhat off topic, but is there a way to:
      a) use OEM 13c to host the files
--OR--
 b) create a super simple web server that the users could access

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you consider a "novice user".

Note first that the following method is circumventing your systems email security.  Do this at your own risk...

Encrypt the data.  For example, using Blowfish and openssl:

```
[~]$ openssl enc -bf -a < file.tar > file.txt
enter bf-cbc encryption password: [password here]
Verifying bf-cbc encryption password: [password here]
[~]
```

To decrypt:

```
[~]$ openssl enc -bf -d -a < file.txt > file.tar
enter bf-cbc decryption password: [password here]
[~]
```

Those commands encrypt the data using the Blowfish cipher (the `-bf` argument) and base64-encode the output (the `-a` option).  The decryption is done by adding the `-d` option.  See [OpenSSL's `enc` documentation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Enc).

Since the output file will be effectively random text characters it's likely to get through any "file type" screening.

Using this, you can almost certainly get *any* type of file through any screening process.

Again, though, this is deliberately circumventing your email systems security.

Comment: Marinaio noted the user was on a corporate PC, so I suspect Windows based.  If so, unlikely user has openssl on it.  Perhaps using the same process Andrew notes, but use crypto/gnupg (GNU Privacy Guard) where there exists Windows ports with GUIs.  Memory is it also supports compression.